# mule extract xml element which is base64 string and dump to file

Tags: xml, serialization, base64, mule, mule-el

In mule, I have a c# class what was serialized with XmlSerializer (over in the microsoft world). The xml serialized class has an element called FileContents that I am trying to work on (xpath = '/Document/_originalfile/FileContents').  Basically, this has a base64 encoded string which is a PDF file. My goal is to extract this "encapsulated" file and write it out on the local file system as a PDF and a local app will process it and do some things to it (Like OCR and superimpose a GUID) and place it in a neighboring directory for another mule flow to pass it around. My issue is getting that darn string out of the XML Element. I have tried as many transformer recipies as I think are possible to the tenth power. I would like someone to explain what I am doing wrong. After much headbaning and such, the closest I ever got was getting the base64 string written to a PDF file that was really only a text file in notepad++... not even close to a real PDF. And then, it was only the first "chunk" of the base64 string. for instance, in Altova, when I look at the element, there is like 26 line breaks. It appears to break out only the first block of the string (out of 26) in the output PDF\text file. I would provide a basic flow here to illustrate what  was attempting to do but, I got so agitated that I broke it trying to "fix" it and have not since been able to re-produce whatever I did. But, for convenience, I have attached the entire serialized class out of the c# app. So, the real live example of XML that I am working with, and consequently getting electronically laughed at. Please help! Thanks in advance! I love mule and want to use it exclusively as it shows much promise. But, I am new to it and despite actually reading a book on it, I am failing miserably. (But, the book was fantastic I would recommend it to anyone getting in to mule)

Here is the class... hope someone out there can just say "Oh, easy dude... just transform it to this, then that, filter this, switch that set-paylod over there and whiz bang pow, you have it output to a file!"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <DocGUID>9e17d0ea-2810-4bdf-87d7-c106867a91f1</DocGUID>
  <_originalfile>
    <FileContents>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</FileContents>
    <NumberOfPages>1</NumberOfPages>
    <OriginalFileLocation>C:\feed1\pdf-sample.pdf</OriginalFileLocation>
  </_originalfile>
  <ContainedPages />
</Document>
```

Also, here is an attempt to portray what I would like to do with a mule configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
    <flow name="XML_Class_to_PDFFlow1" doc:name="XML_Class_to_PDFFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="c:\in" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <set-payload value="#[xpath('/Document/_originalfile/FileContents/text()')]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <object-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <logger message="Payload: #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="c:\out" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Again, much thanks in advance to the mule users of ineffable wisdom! :)

-Edit ----

I made it a little bit closer with this flow. At least the entire base64 element is in the output BUT, it is wrapped in some sort of org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText object. I am getting worried that I will have to code some java to get this to work. :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" version="CE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/current/mule-email.xsd">
    <flow name="EchoFlow" doc:name="EchoFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\in" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
        <all doc:name="All">
            <processor-chain>
            <logger message="Before: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="#[xpath('/Document/_originalfile/FileContents/text()')]"/>
                <logger message="After: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
                <logger message="Finally: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="c:\contents" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
            </processor-chain>
        </all>


    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Since you tagged it C#, post the XML and Base64 code you used.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the xml and base-64 is there...

Comment: I did post the XML file. That is on the bottom of the question. The base 64 element is the //FileContents element. I guess I tagged it wrong though... sorry. It is to extract and make use of the elements in Mule ESB I am totally able to work magic with it inside of .net and visual studio. This is the serialized class that is put in a file inbound endpoint in Mulesoft.org's Mule ESB.

Comment: @UnOjO2010 ah, you tagged c#, so I answered with c#

Comment: I asked for the code, but apparently the question is not for C# ...

Comment: Right Henk. Thanks though. The problem is abstract from c#. I was just explaining where the xml file originated from the be clear and precise. Really, it could be any arbitrary XML file with a base64 string in a element and it will kick my butt just the same. (And realistically, i tagged it as such because I know that in the future, other people will ask this question for a similar reason and they will find it quicker with google. That is how I have searched for it for all of this past week.

Comment: Like you said: _it could be any arbitrary XML_ . So there is no C# angle at all here.

Comment: Got it. I added Mule Expression Language in place of the C# tag you removed. That should make it more relevant. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: So, where is your Mule configuration?

Comment: I can put one up in a few minutes. Mine broke. I will create a similar flow here shortly and see what you think.

Comment: @David Dossot ---OMG!!! You are the author of the book that I was talking about in my post! Holy Cow! I want to shake your hand!!!! Everyone interested in using Mule go read: Mule in Action, if the author of the book will bother to answer my post, that is enough for me to endorse it! Worth every penny!!! http://www.manning.com/dossot/

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is that you're missing `.text` in your XPath expression to get the `String` value of it, instead of the DOM node. See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips#MuleExpressionLanguageTips-XPathSupport

I don't really understand your second flow (why an `all` router? why all these transformers?) so I'm going to try and fix your first attempt:

```
<flow name="XML_Class_to_PDFFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="/tmp/mule/in" />
    <mulexml:xml-to-dom-transformer />
    <set-payload
        value="#[xpath('/Document/_originalfile/FileContents/text()').text]" />
    <base64-decoder-transformer />
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="/tmp/mule/out"
        outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]-#[message.id].pdf" />
</flow>
```

Comment: The all router was remnants of another endpoint I had it posting to. I just didn't remove that because I planned to get it added again once I passed this hurdle. I figured it was easier to post the question if I just file->file flowed it.

Comment: That is a similar flow i see to one i tried before. It does throw an error saying "Message payload is of type: DefaultDocument" when you try to run the xpath. Placing a transformer before setting payload but, after collecting the file does not appear to do anything but cause it to gripe about a payload type. whether that be string, byte[] or whatever. It never seems to just want to go "Oh, look, string.... XML is string, string of XML it is!!!" and process it. What am I missing here? I surely used your flow verbatim, I copied and pasted it! :) Thanks again!

Comment: Grmphfff, sorry, I didn't test my answer, don't have my full env with me right now. Added a `<mulexml:xml-to-dom-transformer />` for good measure, please try.

Comment: That did work for getting past that error. But, It now dumps some odd output into that file which appears to be an array. Maybe that issue where it has line breaks between the element tags has come back to haunt me? I know those are apart of the base64 string. Were you able to get it to output just fine in your test environment? Are you using Linux or windows? I always see differences in the handling of line breaks between the 2 O.S. Thanks for your help, I am beyond grateful. At this point, I am considering a php script to extract the file before it hits mule- that kind of defeats the purpose

Comment: (prolonged facepalm) I forgot the most important bit: the Base64 decoder... After adding it, the configuration in my answer works perfectly. I end up with a PDF file named "This is a test PDF file" and whose content is perfectly decoded!

Comment: Oh and yes, I'm on Linux.

Comment: Okay, I'm not retarded, I swear! But, I cannot for the life of me get the same results that you have gotten. I am now getting this error:
could not access: text; in class: java.util.ArrayList
I am now on Ubuntu 14 LTS, as I Figured that the windows thing might be our problem.  It turns out, it is a cross platform thing, I have this error linux or windows. I'm sorry to continue to bother you. I did however notice that it is indeed the blocks of text that are psuedo recognized in Altova's XML Spy. for some reason, they are broken into line breaks and for everysingle line break, there is a single

Comment: element in that array. So, it is indeed a 1:1 thing. Now, if there is a smart way to concatenate each element together in that array before we shoot it over to the decoder, I think we would be in there. But, my fornext loop attempt did not "cocatenate" anything, it just simply recursively overwrote the payload foreach element in that array. GRRRRRRR! Thanks again, Ill be out of your hair this time, I promise!

Comment: Interesting, it's as if you're receiving several text nodes in `FileContents` while I get only one. Could you try with this XPath: `#[xpath('/Document/_originalfile/FileContents').text]` ?

Comment: I got:
Execution of the expression "xpath('/Document/_originalfile/FileContents').text]" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message  payload is of type: byte[]
 This time, I think I have seen that before in my attempts to extract this element.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what's going on. Everything works fine for me when using the XML you provided with the config I've put in my solution and Mule 3.4.0 CE / Oracle JDK 7 / Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Well, for some reason,  using the "real java" works. But, only on linux. That is ubuntu of course and F20. Never would have dreamed java could care about the underlying O.S. I would like to mark your answer as the correct one but, this was my first question so, I don't have enough reputation points to mark it as such. Instead,  I'll just go buy my buddy Pete a copy of your book. Thanks alot!